# Getting a dictionary value from a variables

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, methods

I have a dictionary where the value is a class, so I'm storing multiple variables within a dictionary per key, for example -

```
public Dictionary<int, Crew> CrewList = new Dictionary<int, Crew>();
var crews = CrewList[x];
int hp = crews.HP;
int attack = crew.Attack;
```

and so forth. My current code is this

```
if (currentCrew.Weapon != "")
{
string weapons = currentCrew.Weapon;
   foreach (var weapone in weaponclass)
   {
       if (weapons == weapone.Name)
       {
            strengthMod += weapone.StrengthMod;
       }
   }
}
```

What I would like is -

```
public void getMethod(Crew crews, var mod, List<ModClasses> modclass)
{
if (crews.mod != "")
    {
    string mods = crews.mod;
       foreach (var mod in modclass)
       {
           if (mods == mod.Name)
           {
                strengthMod += mods.StrengthMod;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version, but basically what I want to do. So is there a way to make the crew.mod part work where it'll replace the 'mod' part of it with whatever variable I'm trying to return?

Comment: You'd have to use reflection, but I'd strongly recommend you consider putting the 'modifiers' into a separate collection instead (e.g. `Dictionary<string, int>`). Then you can access it like `var mod = crew.Modifiers["HP"];`

Comment: But would that sill result in the same thing as crew.HP or crew.strengthMod? My example is a bit simplified, in reality each modifier is a string, which I then will separate via Split(':').

Comment: When you call getModifiers, what are you actually getting?  A `List<KeyValuePair>` for a particular crew?  Why doesn't that method return anything?

Comment: I'm trying to add a value to a public int based on whichever mod and crew I select. I could do it by making an individual chunk of code for each modifier I need, but I figured if this can work, it'll be more manageable.

Comment: This smells a bit of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Can you tell us a bit more about the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I suggest you make a well structured `Modifier` class of some sort, so you don't have to do any string splitting. Use a data structure that reflects the kind of information your modelling as closely as possible.

Comment: Ok so I have a class Crew with various stats (strength, hp, defense, etc.) and also a few strings (weapon, helm, armor). All by those names. In my main class I also have some mod ints such as strengthMod, defenseMod, and so forth. The program then checks the strings of each item, weapon, helm, and armor, and depending on which string is matched to another list with all the values, it then set strengthMod and such to the correct value, so when I click "Fight" attack is equal to strength + strengthMod.

Comment: Your function should be returning this value, not setting some global variable.  If you want to then set the global variable to the returned value, that's cool, but at least you'll have a function that's unit-testable.

Comment: Well the problem isn't so much setting the values, as setting which value I want from my crew. It can't recognize the mod variable as an actual value,

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: Ok, my crewlist has a crew member Bob, with 10 strength, 10 hp, and 8 defense. He also has a weapon "iron sword" and armor "iron breastplate". What should happen is I call getModifers(Bob, weapon) and in the method it'll check bob.weapon against a list I have for a similar string, and then set strengthMod to that value, lets say for this sword, +5. Next I need to do the same except getModifier(Bob, armor) which'll set defenseMod to + 10 or so.

Comment: Do weapon and armor derive from the same interface, i.e. `ICanModify?`

Comment: I updated my code, but weapons and armor each comes from a different csv file that I parsed into a list called weaponsclass and armorclass.

Comment: Forgetting all the extra stuff, what I basically need is a way to get crew.mod where mod is a class value set in the method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think your design is a tad flawed. Here is how I'd of done it. First, I'd of created a generic interface for any kind of item that has a mod:

```
public interface IMod
{
    int HealthMod { get; set; }
    int ManaMod { get; set; }
    int StrengthMod { get; set; }
    int DexterityMod { get; set; }
    int ArmorMod { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you can add more stats to this interface if you wish. Next, I'd create an item class for your items:

```
public class ItemMod : IMod 
{
    // Implement Members
    public int HealthMod { get; set; }
    public int ManaMod { get; set; }
    public int StrengthMod { get; set; }
    public int DexterityMod { get; set; }
    public int ArmorMod { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I'd create an interface for the crew to describe what each crew member "has":

```
public interface ICrew
{
    IMod Weapon { get; set; }
    IMod Helm { get; set; }
    IMod Armor { get; set; }
}
```

So this interface basically says that all crew members will have a Weapon, a Helm, and a piece of armor. You can add more, obviously. Now for your Crew class:

```
public class Crew : ICrew 
{
    // Implement ICrew members
    public IMod Weapon { get; set; }
    public IMod Helm { get; set; }
    public IMod Armor { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BaseHealth { get; set; }
    public int BaseMana { get; set; }
    public int BaseStrength { get; set; }
    public int BaseDexterity { get; set; }
    public int BaseArmor { get; set; }

    public int TotalHealth
    {
        get { return CalculateHealth(); }
    }

    public int TotalMana
    {
        get { return CalculateMana(); }
    }

    public int TotalStrength
    {
        get { return CalculateStrength(); }
    }

    public int TotalDexterity
    {
        get { return CalculateDexterity(); }
    }

    public int TotalArmor
    {
        get { return CalculateArmor(); }
    }

    private int CalculateHealth()
    {
        int additionalHealth = 0;
        if (Weapon != null)
            additionalHealth += Weapon.HealthMod;
        if (Helm != null)
            additionalHealth += Helm.HealthMod;
        if (Armor != null)
            additionalHealth += Armor.HealthMod;
        return additionalHealth + BaseHealth;
    }

    private int CalculateMana()
    {
        int additionalMana = 0;
        if (Weapon != null)
            additionalMana += Weapon.ManaMod;
        if (Helm != null)
            additionalMana += Helm.ManaMod;
        if (Armor != null)
            additionalMana += Armor.ManaMod;
        return additionalMana + BaseMana;
    }

    private int CalculateStrength()
    {
        int additionalStrength = 0;
        if (Weapon != null)
            additionalStrength += Weapon.StrengthMod;
        if (Helm != null)
            additionalStrength += Helm.StrengthMod;
        if (Armor != null)
            additionalStrength += Armor.StrengthMod;
        return additionalStrength + BaseStrength;
    }

    private int CalculateDexterity()
    {
        int additionalDexterity = 0;
        if (Weapon != null)
            additionalDexterity += Weapon.DexterityMod;
        if (Helm != null)
            additionalDexterity += Helm.DexterityMod;
        if (Armor != null)
            additionalDexterity += Armor.DexterityMod;
        return additionalDexterity + BaseDexterity;
    } 

    private int CalculateArmor()
    {
        int additionalArmor = 0;
        if (Weapon != null)
            additionalArmor += Weapon.ArmorMod;
        if (Helm != null)
            additionalArmor += Helm.ArmorMod;
        if (Armor != null)
            additionalArmor += Armor.ArmorMod;
        return additionalArmor + BaseArmor;

    }       
}
```

Finally, here is how you would use it:

```
var shortSword = new ItemMod();
shortSword.Name = "Short Sword of Darkness";
shortSword.ArmorMod = 15;
shortSword.HealthMod = 20;

var helm = new ItemMod();
helm.Name = "Glorious Helm of Madness";
helm.ArmorMod = 95;
helm.HealthMod = 82;
helm.DexterityMod = 12;

var breastPlate = new ItemMod();
breastPlate.ArmorMod = 145;
breastPlate.HealthMod = 33;
breastPlate.StrengthMod = 49;

var crew = new Crew();
crew.Name = "Jon";
crew.BaseHealth = 15;
crew.BaseMana = 9;
crew.BaseStrength = 25;
crew.BaseDexterity = 10;
crew.BaseArmor = 50;

crew.Weapon = shortSword;
crew.Helm = helm;
crew.Armor = breastPlate;

Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} Health!", crew.Name, crew.TotalHealth);
```

In addition, you could replace some of those properties with a generic list. For example, Jon might have the ability to dual wield swords, in which case, he could carry two swords.

Comment: Thanks, though I did quite a bit of modification, this did help. Didn't really answer my main problem though, just bypassed it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is

```
crew.Mod
```

instead of

```
crew["Mod"]
```

What you need is an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you're after:

```
public int getMethod(
    Crew crews,
    Func<Crew, string> modName,
    Func<ModClasses, int> modValue,
    List<ModClasses> modclass)
{
    string mods = mod(crews);
    return mods == ""
        ? 0
        : modclass
            .Where(m => mods == m.Name)
            .Select(m => modValue(m))
            .Sum();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
strengthMod += getMethod(crews, c => c.StrengthModName, mc => mc.StrengthMod, modclasses);
hpMod += getMethod(crews, c => c.HpModName, mc => mc.HpMod, modclasses);
```